# how to add more animations to the stage when clicking a button in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

i want to add more fish to my flash fish tank by clicking a button..i tried this code but my fish animation is not getting animated after i click the button..and i'm using **action script 3**..

```
    function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Start your custom code
    // This example code displays the words "Mouse clicked" in the Output panel.
    trace("Mouse clicked");

    addChild(f3);
    addChild(eat)   ;
    addChild(hello) ;
    addChild(f2)    ;
    addChild(f1)    ;
    // End your custom code



}
```

**f1,f2,f3,eat,hello** are my fishes..

This is my **infinite scrolling** code..all the fishes are in **separate layers**..so for each layer i have put this code..by just changing the instance name and the function.

```
    f3.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fnewm);
function fnewm(evt:Event)
{   
    if(f3.x + f3.width <= 0) //movieclip is outside left side of stage
    {
        //set new position
        f3.x = stage.stageWidth;
    }
    else
        f3.x -= 5;

}
```

Comment: Do you see "Mouse clicked" message in console when you click you button?

Comment: No..i cant see anything like that @ZuzEL

Comment: Did you attach an event listener to the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you "Mouse clicked" message don't show in console I can assume either of two options:

1. Somehow you didn't setup event listener to the button;
2. Your button is not on the top layer so the click is not registered because it is hidden by something.

I can't tell you exactly, but you can try manually set button's depth. More info on how to do it can be found [here](http://www.foundation-flash.com/tutorials/changingdepths/)